# create a fastify porject by fastify generate xxx. how move xxx to aws lambda

Tags: lambda, fastify

in local env, i need run "npm run dev" successfully after genereate a fastify project by fastify generate.
I found npm run dev = fastify start -l info app.js. it refer to node_modules/fastify-cli/start.js.

should i move start.js to lambda?

Answer (score 0):

In the doc, there is a how-to guide to [opt out `fastify start`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli#migrating-out-of-fastify-cli-start)